# How to get a property of an item in arrayList<CustomClass>

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-listview, arraylist

I have an ArrayList itemsArray, where Item class has 3 properties viz. ItemName, Price and Quantity.
Consider I added one item to the itemsArray let's say e.g Beer, I added Beer as an ItemName, 4 as Quantity and 200 as Price. 
Now itemsArray is of size 1 as one element is there inside.
Now next time when I add Beer again with same price and 1 as quantity, it should replace the existing item in the itemsArray just by modifying it's quantity (Now quantity should be 4+1=5). So the only record in the ArrayList should be (Beer, 200, 5)

```
public void getAddedItems(Items item){


          for (int i = 0; i < itemsArray.size(); i++) {
                if (item.ItemName == itemsArray.get(i).ItemName) {
                    int quant = itemsArray.get(i).quantity;
                    item.quantity = item.quantity + quant;
                    itemsArray.set(i,item);
                    isPresent=true;
                   // countSideList--;
                }
            }

          if(!isPresent) {
                itemsArray.add(countSideList, item);
                countSideList++;

          }



        adapter = new ItemsAdapter1(getActivity(),itemsArray);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        list1.invalidateViews();
        list1.setAdapter(adapter);




    }
}
```

**If I use this code and consider the same example that I have given, It stores the one single record with quantity 1, but I want quantity to be 4+1=5;**

Comment: I think you should understand basic java principles before posting such a question this sounds like a basic object data encapsulation and then you apply those principles to using an array list and adding your data. But this really depends on how exactly you want to deal with your data and collecting it.

Comment: consider using a Map, other wise you will have to iterate through the listArray (unless you still have the object in memory）

Comment: @JoxTraex There is a reason behind I asked this question. I know the concept of object encapsulation and how to apply this concept in real time applications. I already tried the solution you might have thought about when I posted this question. Also, I expected the kind of answer that you have given. But I expect someone to answer who can think beyond criticising others. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

If you google ArrayList, it has remove(item) and add(item) methods.
remove(item) will remove the matching item from the list, and the comparison is done using item.equals(). If you implement item.equals() to match on ItemName, then you could:

```
myList.remove(newItem);
myList.add(newItem);
```

The remove may fail if there is no existing item, but you don't care.

Caveat: If you then use item.equals() elsewhere then it will match if the names are equal, even if the other fields are different. i.e. two 'Beer's will always compare as equal.

Comment: Hey I already tried all that. But when I try to add the second record to the list, I actually want quantity of second item to get added with the quantity of fist item, and instead of storing 2 different items, it should store only one.

Comment: You can use myList.IndexOf(newItem); and myList.get(index); to get the existing 'beer' and add it to your newItem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HashMap instead. HashMap maintains unique keys so when you try to add data with same key than it will overwrite the values of existing key. In your case, you can use it like:

```
HashMap<String, CustomClass> map = new HashMap<String, CustomClass>();
map.put("Beer", yourCustomClassObj);
...
...
if(map.containsKey("Beer"))
{
  CustomClass obj = map.get("Beer");
  obj.quantity = obj.quantity+ newQty;
  map.put("Beer", obj);
}
```

Comment: I want to add that with a Map you can also first try to `get("Beer")`, if it returns a non-null object, then you increment quantity. Otherwise do what @Prashant Patel mentioned.